# Building image on a docker container for running own Django app

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to build an image for run in a Docker container with an own existing Django app doing the following command

```
    sudo docker build -t avilaholding/clubmercado ~/Documents/docker/cmimage
```

but I get this error with psycopg2 instead

```
Collecting pathspec==0.3.4 (from -r /srv/clubmercado/requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading pathspec-0.3.4.tar.gz
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r /srv/clubmercado/requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5wxAAo/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r $DOCKYARD_SRVPROJ/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think it might be because it's running on python 2.7 but I want it to run on python 3.5. I have both versions installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

Also, when I execute 
`pip --version`
or 
`pip3 --version`

it will say that the installed version is already version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it running

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev
```